# Is it possible to render recharts tooltip event when there is no value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, reactstrap

Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/obg92kw3/

I want to render tooltip when hovering over categories without value. Like `Page C`, `Page D`, `Page E`.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you just need to give them 0 values. Updated the jsfiddle to show it working here http://jsfiddle.net/obg92kw3/1/.

`data` should now look like this:

```
const data = [
      {name: 'Page A', uv: 4000},
      {name: 'Page B', uv: 3000},
      {name: 'Page C', uv: 0},
      {name: 'Page D', uv: 0},
      {name: 'Page E', uv: 0},
      {name: 'Page F', uv: 2390},
      {name: 'Page G', uv: 3490},
];
```

Comment: Right, but for this chart `0` and `undefined` have different meanings.

0 - the actual value is 0.
`undefined` - the value is missing. So in my custom tooltip, I would say something like "sorry, but data for this particular date is missing".

Comment: Did u find any solution for data missing and want to hide or show tooltip